# A timer suitable for webgame "ticks"

Tags: c#, loops, web, timer

im trying to create a timer to "tick" and created this timer with a little google help. 
It works perfectly in console, but when i added it in a website, it seems my computer is running at full capasity, and the site is loading slowly and not function properly. 
Can i use this or do i need to start over?

```
namespace ticket

{
    class Program
    {
        public static int counttick = 0;
        public static int ticks = 0;
        static void LoopingFunction()
        {
            while (counttick <= 20)
            {
                int dwStartTime = System.Environment.TickCount;

                while (true)
                {

                 if (System.Environment.TickCount - dwStartTime > 1000) break; //1000 milliseconds 

                }

                counttick++;
                if (counttick == 20)
                {

                    ticks++;

                    counttick = 0;
                }
            }
        }

      protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          Label2.Text = "Ticks: " + Convert.ToString(ticks);

            LoopingFunction();
        }
    }
}`
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve? what kind of ticks you want?

Comment: i want a timer to continue "forever" and make it add +1 to a variable after a certain time. here ive made it for 20 seconds. in "if (counttick == 20) im going to add values to the Database.

Comment: What do you want to do on the tick, update the client?

Answer (score 0):

Remove:

```
while (true)
{
   if (System.Environment.TickCount - dwStartTime > 1000) break; //1000 milliseconds
}
```

And use:

```
System.Threading.Sleep(1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try System.Threading.[Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx) class.

Answer (score 0):

In web applications i don't recommend using static variables, because you really never know when you IIS will recycle the app pool and you static varitable will become 0. rather you should try something to persistence storage. and use to Try System.Threading.Timer class to update the value in may be a Database table or some file.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I'll just give another approach. I needed a similar tick loop that runs at about 25 frames per second. I have a class called `ApplicationLoop` which, when constructed starts a thread. That thread is my application loop. (Hence the obvious class name.)

So I have a few constants, to determine my frame rate, and a frame-skip fallback value. Basically, when a task takes more time than 40ms (1000 / 25 = 40), I loop through all the tasks again to "catch-up". But I only do this a number of times.

```
private const int MAX_FRAMESKIP = 5;
private const int UPDATE_SKIP_TICKS = 1000 / UPDATE_TICKS_PER_SECOND;
private const int UPDATE_TICKS_PER_SECOND = 25;
```

My thread function:

```
private void UpdateLoop()
{
    ulong ticks = 0UL;
    _isRunning = true;
    var next = DateTime.Now.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond;

    while (_isRunning)
    {
        var now = DateTime.Now.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond;
        int loops = 0;

        while ((now > next) && _isRunning && (loops < MAX_FRAMESKIP))
        {
            ProcessTasks(ticks);

            next += UPDATE_SKIP_TICKS;
            loops++;
            ticks++;
        }

        AccurateSleep(1);
    }
}
```

My class contains a `Subscribe()` function which takes a delegate. I store that callback into a `List` and the `ProcessTasks()` function calls each subscribed function.

You can replace the `AccurateSleep()` function with a simple `Thread.Sleep(1)` call, but be aware that the default time-slice for a sleep is about 15ms.

```
[DllImport("winmm.dll")]
private static extern uint timeBeginPeriod(uint period);

[DllImport("winmm.dll")]
private static extern uint timeEndPeriod(uint period);

private static void AccurateSleep(int sleep)
{
    timeBeginPeriod(1);
    Thread.Sleep(sleep);
    timeEndPeriod(1);
}
```